# Is there special function to call for updating session in the newest (beta) next auth?

Tags: session, next.js, next-auth

If you don't want to read context just skip down to the question where I wrote "---->".

It has be bugging me a lot, in Next-Auth v4 we use update for updating session (at least how I did it), but I've recently switched to Next-Auth v5 (Beta version when you do yarn add next-auth@beta) and everything seems too perfect, in means that we only use one call:

```
import { auth } from "@/auth";

const session = await auth();
```

And with this we can call whatever we want from session when we set it up in our auth.ts file. But I have a problem with updating session with this implementation.

For example I was doing 2FA set up for project and to enable it you need to click on a "Slider" component I've made that is like a switch left to right, and when you do verify 2FA, slider is on the correct "right" side because we have enabled it, but when I refresh the page it's back to previous state which is incorrect since in database field isTwoFactoEnabled is set to "Enabled".

----> Question is, is there a new function with Next-Auth v5 that updates session or do I have to use old way or is that removed from v5?

Example code (Child component - Information2FA.tsx):

```
"use client";

// REACTJS IMPORTS
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// NEXTJS IMPORTS
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

// COMPONENTS
import TwoFASetup from '@/app/components/Pages/settings/privacy_and_security/Information2FAComponents/TwoFASetup';
import TwoFAEnableModal from '@/app/components/Pages/settings/privacy_and_security/Information2FAComponents/TwoFAEnableModal';
import TwoFADisableModal from '@/app/components/Pages/settings/privacy_and_security/Information2FAComponents/TwoFADisableModal';

// HOOKS
import { useNotification } from '@/app/hooks/useNotification/useNotification';

// ACTIONS
import { enable2FA } from '@/app/actions/settings/privacy_and_security/enable2FA';
import { verify2FA } from '@/app/actions/settings/privacy_and_security/verify2FA';
import { disable2FA } from '@/app/actions/settings/privacy_and_security/disable2FA';

interface Information2FAProps {
initial2FA: string;
initialEmail: string;
}

const Information2FA: React.FC\<Information2FAProps\> = ({ initial2FA, initialEmail }) =\> {
const t = useTranslations();
const showNotification = useNotification();

    const [isTwoFactorEnabled, setIsTwoFactorEnabled] = useState(initial2FA);
    
    const [secret, setSecret] = useState('');
    const [tempSecret, setTempSecret] = useState('');
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    
    const [isEnable2FAMenuOpen, setIsEnable2FAMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isDisable2FAMenuOpen, setIsDisable2FAMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    
    const handleTokenChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setToken(e.target.value);
    };
    
    const handleCloseMenus = () => {
        if(isEnable2FAMenuOpen) setIsEnable2FAMenuOpen(false);
        if(isDisable2FAMenuOpen) setIsDisable2FAMenuOpen(false);
    
        setIsTwoFactorEnabled(initial2FA);
    };
    
    const clientActionEnable2FA = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await enable2FA();
    
            if (response.success && response.tempSecret) {
                setTempSecret(response.tempSecret);
                setIsTwoFactorEnabled('Enabled');
            } else {
                showNotification("error", t('CLIENT_ERROR_2FA_ENABLING_FAILED'));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            showNotification("error", t('CLIENT_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ERROR'));
        }
    };
    
    const clientActionVerify2FA = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await verify2FA(token, tempSecret);
    
            if (response.success) {
                setSecret(tempSecret);
                setIsEnable2FAMenuOpen(false);
            } else {
                showNotification("error", t('CLIENT_ERROR_2FA_TOKEN_FAILED'));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            showNotification("error", t('CLIENT_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ERROR'));
        }
    };
    
    const clientActionDisable2FA = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await disable2FA(token);
    
            if (response.success) {
                setIsTwoFactorEnabled('Disabled');
                setSecret('');
                setTempSecret('');
                setIsDisable2FAMenuOpen(false);
            } else {
                showNotification("error", t('CLIENT_ERROR_2FA_DISABLING_FAILED'));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            showNotification("error", t('CLIENT_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ERROR'));
        }
    };
    
    const toggle2FA = () => {
        if (isTwoFactorEnabled === 'Disabled') {
            clientActionEnable2FA();
            setIsEnable2FAMenuOpen(true);
        } else {
            setIsDisable2FAMenuOpen(true);
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <TwoFASetup 
                isTwoFactorEnabled={isTwoFactorEnabled} 
                toggle2FA={toggle2FA}
            />
    
            {isEnable2FAMenuOpen && (
                <TwoFAEnableModal 
                    initialEmail={initialEmail}
                    tempSecret={tempSecret}
                    token={token}
                    handleTokenChange={handleTokenChange}
                    clientActionVerify2FA={clientActionVerify2FA}
                    onClose={handleCloseMenus}
                />
            )}
    
            {isDisable2FAMenuOpen && (
                <TwoFADisableModal
                    token={token}
                    handleTokenChange={handleTokenChange}
                    clientActionDisable2FA={clientActionDisable2FA}
                    onClose={handleCloseMenus}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );

};

export default Information2FA;
```

Example code (Main/Parent component - page.tsx):

```
// REACTJS IMPORTS
import React from 'react';

// NEXTJS IMPORTS
import { auth } from '@/auth';

// COMPONENTS
import Layout from "@/app/components/Layouts/Layout/Layout";

import SettingsHeader from '@/app/components/Layouts/SettingsHeader/SettingsHeader';

import InformationEmail from '@/app/components/Pages/settings/privacy_and_security/InformationEmail';
import InformationPassword from '@/app/components/Pages/settings/privacy_and_security/InformationPassword';
import Information2FA from '@/app/components/Pages/settings/privacy_and_security/Information2FA';

export default async function SettingsAccount() {
    const session = await auth();

    return (
        <Layout>
            <SettingsHeader activeTab="privacy_and_security" />
    
            <InformationEmail
                initialEmail={session?.user.email} 
            />
    
            <InformationPassword />
    
            <Information2FA
                initial2FA={session?.user.isTwoFactorEnabled as string}
                initialEmail={session?.user.email as string}
            />
        </Layout>
    );

};
```

I've tried looking into documentation for the newest implementation, but haven't found anything related to updating session with "possible" new function that has maybe come with v5.

Also I've tried searching a lot for similar issues people had, but I didn't seem to even find that much topics about v5 at all, not to mention about updating session in this version.

Documentation I checked: https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly! Here's the revised version:

#### You have two methods available:

1. **The new server-side `update` function:**

   In version 5, the `NextAuth()` function returns:

   ```js
   import NextAuth from "next-auth";

   export const {
     auth,
     handlers: { GET, POST },
     signIn,
     signOut,
     update,
   } = NextAuth({
     // ...
   });
   ```

   To update the session server-side, you can utilize the `update` function by passing a session object.

   Its type is defined as:

   ```js
   update: (
      data: Partial<Session | { user: Partial<Session["user"]> }>
   ) => Promise<Session | null>
   ```

   For instance:

   ```js
   await update({ user: { email: updatedEmail } });
   ```
2. **Client-side usage with `useSession`:**

   Similar to version 4:

   ```js
   "use client";

   import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
   // ...
   const { update } = useSession();
   // ...
   await update({
     ...user,
     ...updatedUser,
   });
   ```

   Then, you can listen for updates in the `jwt` callback:

   ```js
   const {auth} = NextAuth({
     callbacks: {
       async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session }) {
         // Check if the trigger is calling update()
         if (trigger === "update" && session) {
           // If so, the data passed to `update(data)` represents the session prop
           token = { ...user, ...(session as AuthUser) }
         };
         // ...
         return token;
       }
     }
   })
   ```